# Converting Objective-C Method to C#

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I am trying to convert the following objective-c method to C#, but I'm having trouble.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView moveItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath;
```

Is this correct?

```
public void moveItemAtIndexPath(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPathToIndexPath, NSIndexPath FromIndexPath)
```

Comment: Just replace `NSIndexPathToIndexPath` by `NSIndexPath ToIndexPath`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the following:

```
public void moveItemAtIndexPath(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath fromIndexPath, NSIndexPath toIndexPath)
```

though 'public/protected/private' is all upon you.